# Move Waveform across ScrollViewer Window

Tags: wpf, window, clock, scrollviewer, naudio

I have plotted a waveform (left channel of audio file) on a canvas inside a scroll viewer. I would like the canvas (with the waveform as its content) to "move across" the scrollviewer's visible window. The point of this is to be able to watch the waveform move across the screen and even though the audio file being plotted may be several minutes long, only a window of specified time is visible (a minute clip, perhaps). I would like it bound to a clock, so that when the clock starts, the waveform begins to move (or alternatively, the scroll viewer's horizontal offset advances). I used Naudio to plot the waveform, using C# & WPF. The plotted waveform is the graph of all the bytes in the file sampled every 100 milliseconds. How do I keep the clock and the viewwindow in sync? Any help or place to start would be appreciated as this is my first project working with this sort of thing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, then you can programmatically scrolls the contents of `Canvas` depending on the time. Below I will show a sample algorithm.

You can scroll the programmatically like this:

```
scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + 5); // Horizontal scroll through 5 units
```

Work with the timer might look like:

```
int InitInterval = Interval; // init interval
System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ScrollCanvas);

// set the interval
if (InitInterval > 0)
{
    myTimer.Interval = InitInterval;
}

// turn on timer
myTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Listing of `ScrollCanvas():`

```
private void ScrollCanvas(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // some code
    // ...

    // implementing scrolling
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
    {
        scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + 5); 
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample code. I am using a timeline and clock for sync, not a timer, but the way to scroll with the horizontal offset is helpful and I have implemented it. The clock however is more fine than my data points, so I will check when my clock is on a multiple of my data points (I have one data point per 1/10 of a second) and then on those clock times I will scroll to the horizontal offset of the width of one data point on my plot. Thanks again.